# Pass By Reference, Getting Incorrect Answer in C++

Tags: c++

This is a simple Pass By Reference Problem to calculate the salary after tax, when directly printing "income-income*tax" it's giving the expected output but when the value of variable is updated it's giving a wrong answer.
It is working fine in the online compiler.

What could be the reason of this?

```
//  Using Reference Variable

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void incomeAfterTax(int &income)
{
    float tax = 0.10;

    cout << income-income*tax << endl;          // printing 90

    income = income - income*tax;
    cout << income << endl;                     // but here it is 89
}
int main()
{
    int salary = 100;
    cout << "Total Salary: " << salary << endl;
    incomeAfterTax(salary);
    cout << "Income After Tax: " << salary;      // prints 89 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get `90` for the different outputs, but I'm assuming that this is likely just a floating point math issue.

Comment: Please provide your compiler and build options.  I imagine most people will get the "correct" output.

Comment: `income-income*tax` is a floating point value that is a tiny bit less than 90. Printing rounds the value, assigning it to an int discards the fractional part.

Comment: Also FWIW your function would probably be better named `applyTax`/`deductTax` or similar as it modifies the original value, rather than returning a new one

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a floating point issue; were the result of 'income-tax' is being converted to an integer.

The issue is avoidable by using the round() function in  (for C++11). (roundf() if using C99)

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

void incomeAfterTax(int& income)
{
    const float tax = 0.10;
    cout << income-income*tax << endl;          
    const float tax_amt = static_cast<float>(income) * tax; // income is int, cast to float
    income -= round(tax_amt);  //round the float value to closest int
    cout << income << endl;                     
}
int main()
{
    int salary = 100;
    cout << "Total Salary: " << salary << endl;
    incomeAfterTax(salary);
    cout << "Income After Tax: " << salary;      

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was floating point issue, working fine using the round() function. Thank You!